# change order of array elements each loop iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a array looking like that:

`numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Now i have a for-loop and i want that after each iteration the order of the array will change like:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3]
[3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2] .....
```

how to archive this?

```
for (i=0; i <5; i++){
  //change order of array?
  console.log(numbers);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried writing a loop that will move every item forward once? Even if it doesn’t work, please include it.

Comment: i can do  `numbers[i] = numbers[i+1]` but there is the error that the array gets bigger.. after each execution of this loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `unshift()` and `pop()`

```js
var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for (var i=0; i < 5; i++) {
  numbers.unshift(numbers.pop());
  console.log(numbers)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible besides the answer of Nenad Vracar is the use of the `splice` method:

```js
var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for (var i=0; i < 5; i++) {
  numbers.unshift(numbers.splice(numbers.length - 1, 1)[0]);
  console.log(numbers);
}
```

However, the previous answer is more elegant.